# How to detect EOF in piped data?

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I'm creating a C-program under Linux, and I want to catch FFMpeg's output-data and forward it. To do so, I'm calling FFMpeg via (an implementation of) popen2. It all is working fine: I'm able to get FFMpeg's data out of the pipe via `read()`. Things start to get awkward if FFMpeg stops working. `read()` seems to be blocking, which is the expected behaviour, but it never exits when the pipe is closed.

I learned that, for `read()` to break and detect an EOF, the pipe should be closed on both ends, so when I detect that FFMpeg is crashed or killed, I close the reading-end of my pipe. I'm assuming that, since FFMpeg is closed, it disconnects its end of the pipe.

My assumption seems to be wrong: when I close the reading-end of the pipe by using `close()`, the program still seems to be hanging in `read()`.

Would somebody be able to explain me what's wrong with my assumption and point me in the right direction so that I can properly detect when the program that I'm piping to or from (in this case FFMpeg) has stopped sending data?

The relevant code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include "helper.h"

#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1


FILE *sink_stream;
int ffmpeg_sink;

pid_t popen2_2(const char **command, int *infp, int *outfp);
void* pthread_sink_ffmpeg(void *arg);

pid_t popen2_2(const char **command, int *infp, int *outfp)
{

    int p_stdin[2], p_stdout[2];
    pid_t pid;
    
    int devNull = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);

    if (pipe(p_stdin) != 0 || pipe(p_stdout) != 0)
        return -1;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
        return pid;
    else if (pid == 0) //first fork
    {
        close(p_stdin[WRITE]);
        dup2(p_stdin[READ], READ); 
        
        close(p_stdout[READ]);
        dup2(p_stdout[WRITE], WRITE);
        
        //dup2(devNull,2); //pipes stderr to /dev/null....

        execvp(*command, command);
        _exit(1);
    }

    if (infp == NULL)
    {
        close(p_stdin[WRITE]);
        close(p_stdin[READ]);
    }
    else
    {
        *infp = p_stdin[WRITE];
    }
    
    if (outfp == NULL)
    {
        close(p_stdout[WRITE]);
        close(p_stdout[READ]);
    }
    else
    {
        *outfp = p_stdout[READ];
    }
    
    return pid;
}

void* pthread_sink_ffmpeg(void *arg)
{
    char *pbuffer;

    int length, res;
    
    pbuffer = malloc(4096);

    while(1)
    {
        /* Wait for input */    
        dbgfprintf("Waiting for input...");
                
        while( (length = read(ffmpeg_sink, pbuffer, 1024)) )
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Read [ %d ]...\r", length);
        }

        /* RIP */
        dbgfprintf("Done for now..");
        
    }

    free(pbuffer);

}

int main( void )
{
    int wstatus;
    pid_t child_pid, w;
    pthread_t t_ffmpeg_source;
        
    const char *command_ffmpeg[] = {"ffmpeg", 
        "-hide_banner",
        "-re",
        "-i", "http://relay.ah.fm/192k",
        "-c:a", "libfdk_aac",
        "-profile:a", "aac_he_v2",
        "-b:a", "128k",
        "-f", "adts",
        "pipe:1",
        NULL};
        
    child_pid = popen2_2(command_ffmpeg, NULL, &ffmpeg_sink);
    dbgfprintf("Started ffmpeg with pid [ %d ]...", child_pid);
    
    pthread_create(&t_ffmpeg_source, NULL, pthread_sink_ffmpeg, NULL);
    
    do {
       w = waitpid(child_pid, &wstatus, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
    } while (!WIFEXITED(wstatus) && !WIFSIGNALED(wstatus)); 
    
    dbgfprintf("ffmpeg terminated...");
    close(ffmpeg_sink);
    
    pthread_join(t_ffmpeg_source, NULL);
}
```

This code is able to start the program, receive it's data, detect the execvp'd program crash/kill, but it never gets out of `read()` when the execvp'd program is killed.

I've also tried to read the pipe as a filestream;

```
    sink_stream = fdopen(ffmpeg_sink, "r");
    while( !feof(sink_stream) )
    {
        length = fread(pbuffer, 1, 4096, sink_stream);
            
        fprintf(stderr, "Read [ %d ]...\r", length);
    }
```

..which gives the same result: it reads the data but it doesn't get out of `fread()`.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The child still has `p_stdin[READ]` and `p_stdout[WRITE]` open when it execs the command. Perhaps you should close them after the `dup2` calls.

Comment: Your current while loop is ineffective.  There are 3 possible outcomes: error (`read` returns a negative number), data received (`read` returns a positive number), and end-of-stream (`read` returns zero, but possibly only once and after that it's an error with negative return).  You handle zero by exiting the inner `while` loop but that `while(1)` runs forever, and you have no error-checking at all.

Comment: Also there's no reason to call `malloc` with a small constant.  Just use an automatic array declaration (and possibly store a pointer in a global variable).

Comment: You also need to read [**Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the comments.
Indeed, the while-loops are ineffective, but I've isolated this code from a bigger project so that I could troubleshoot this issue more effectively. That's also why the `malloc()` is still there, and indeed it is very pointless.

As Ian stated, it turns out to be as simple as closing the `p_stdin[READ]` and `p_stdout[WRITE]`. It all makes sense now: I figured that I didn't need to close them since the execvp'd program is using them but that's the whole thing: the execvp'd program (child) is using them, and not me (the parent).

`popen2_2()` now looks like this:

```
{

    int p_stdin[2], p_stdout[2];
    pid_t pid;
    
    int devNull = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);

    if (pipe(p_stdin) != 0 || pipe(p_stdout) != 0)
        return -1;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
        return pid;
    else if (pid == 0) //first fork
    {
        close(p_stdin[WRITE]);
        dup2(p_stdin[READ], READ); 
        
        close(p_stdout[READ]);
        dup2(p_stdout[WRITE], WRITE);
        
        //dup2(devNull,2); //pipes stderr to /dev/null....

        execvp(*command, command);
        _exit(1);
    }

    if (infp == NULL)
    {
        close(p_stdin[WRITE]);
        close(p_stdin[READ]);
    }
    else
    {
        close(p_stdin[READ]);
        *infp = p_stdin[WRITE];
    }
    
    if (outfp == NULL)
    {
        close(p_stdout[WRITE]);
        close(p_stdout[READ]);
    }
    else
    {
        *outfp = p_stdout[READ];
        close(p_stdout[WRITE]);
    }
    
    return pid;
}
```

I can happily continue coding now! Thanks all :)